# ruby:union of two regular expressions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two regular expressions r1 and r2 and I have to form a regular which is union of both two. How can it be done in ruby ?

Comment: `Regexp.union` is your friend.

Answer (score 5):

Use this method [`::union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union).

> Return a Regexp object that is the union of the given patterns, i.e., will match any of its parts. The patterns can be Regexp objects, in which case their options will be preserved, or Strings. If no patterns are given, returns /(?!)/. The behavior is unspecified if any given pattern contains capture.

```
Regexp.union(r1, r2)
```

Comment: Is it really that hard to find a method called `union` in a class called `Regexp` if you are asking about how to *union* two `Regexp`s?

Comment: @JörgWMittag yeah, no kidding. I am amazed that this received 4 upvotes almost instantaneously.

Comment: @BradWerth: Oh, I'm not talking about the answer. The answer is fine. I'm talking about the *question*. If I were looking for a way to union two `Regexp`s, the first thing I would do is look whether there is a method `union` in the `Regexp` class … and look … there it is!

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm not trying to dog on Arup, who is super helpful. Or to get the answer unselected, which it unfortunately has. On the other hand, answers to obvious questions do not usually do so well, and the questions themselves are typically downvoted into oblivion. It's also almost impossible to ask an easy ruby question that hasn't been answered on the site several times already.